# isotope append method removes current elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am attempting to append elements to a list using the .load() method to retrieve elements from another page.

But when I use this method it is removing the current DOM elements and replacing them, rather than appending them to the list.

Any help  would be much appreciated.

Code below:

```
var $container = $('#container');
$('#insert a').click(function () {
          var newEls;

          $container.load('../pages/2.html .element', function () {
              newEls = $(this);
          });
          $container.isotope('insert', $(newEls));

          return false;
      });
```

Comment: I should note the example above uses insert, I have experimented with append and insert. There are also no JavaScript errors

Answer (score 0):

Surely you should be telling isotope to insert after they have been loaded.

e.g.

```
      $container.load('../pages/2.html .element', function () {
          newEls = $(this);
          $container.isotope('insert', $(newEls));
      });
```

otherwise you are inserting the current contents (or an empty div) before loading them.

Your `$container.isotope('insert', $(newEls));` is executing before the load even starts (the load is asynchronous so you can only trust something to run against the loaded data if it is in the callback/function).

In addition to this, you are reloading the entire contents of the '#container' so it simply erases the previous children. You need to append the content, e.g. by loading into a dummy element then appending to your container.

### maybe something like this (untested):

```
var $container = $('#container');
$('#insert a').click(function () {
          var $newEls;
          $container.append('<div id="#loadme"></div>');
          var $loadme = $('#loadme');
          $('#loadme').load('../pages/2.html .element', function () {
              $newEls = $loadme.children();
              $loadme.children().unwrap();
              $container.isotope('insert', $newEls);
          });

          return false;
      });
```

Normally I would not use `load` in this situation, but an AJAX `get` call and append the returned elements. Much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did originally write the code as mentioned above and it comes up with the same issue. Although interestingly when you run the code in your example, isotope has clearly run and created the correct layout as there is a large gap where the original elements had been in the list. However in both scenarios the original elements are still not displaying.

Comment: You definitely need it in this order, but that would be because you are loading the entire contents of '#container' and not appending it :) I will update answer.

Comment: That's great, thank you, makes sense! Tested it and all is working as expected. The reason I am using load here rather than get is because I want to use a query string to call another page which then just renders back the selected html elements specified in the load function. I'd be interested if you think there is a better scenario.

Comment: I believe `load` just calls `get` behind the scenes. Get is just a HTML request after all. The only extra bit you need to do is wrap the return in `$(data).find('.element')` and insert that. I generally use a partial page for rendering this sort of thing so you aren't wasting bandwidth on extra fluff that then gets thrown away.